# how to create to_sql create_engine

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas-to-sql

I'm trying to add data frame information to PostgreSQL's table.

But I don't know how to create an engine.
It's very likely related to connection to SQL server, but I could not figure out how to create it.

The example I saw on the to_sql document is:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)
```

And what I tried is:

```
param_dic = {'host': 'localhost', 'database':'databasename', 'user':'username', 'password':'password' }
conn = pgsql.connect(**param_dic)
cursor = conn.cursor()

for filename in work_dir.glob('excel_filename.xlsx'):
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)
    df.to_sql('table name', conn, if_exists='replace')
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

Comment: Those look to be two separate modes of connection. It is not clear where ```pgsql``` is coming from. For the ```create_engine``` portion see [Postgres](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#postgresql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)
```

this seems incomplete. normally you'd put the connection string here, not just "sqlite".

I guess what you're trying to do is

```
# note, put your actual credentials here
engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/test', echo=False)
```

you can then create a connection based on this engine, like

```
with engine.connect() as con:
    # etc...
    df.to_sql('table name', conn, if_exists='replace')
    # etc...
```

or just con = engine.connect()

Comment: Actually I already solved my problem myself. But I directly put the engine to df.to_sql like df.to_sql('table name', engine, if_exists = 'replace'). What's the real purpose using engine.connet()?

Comment: engine.connect() just creates a connection. apparently df.to_sql() accepts an engine as a parameter, so you really dont need a connection. idk how that works but I wouldnt have suggested using a connection anyway if you didnt have it in your example.